# Tooltips not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

OK, I am baffled on how to get Bootstrap 3 Tooltip working.
Bootstrap Tooltip "instructions"
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Says to trigger using:

`$('#example').tooltip(options)`

then HTML to write

`<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!">Hover over me</a>`

No matter what I do, I cannot seem to get it working. There is no ID named example in their example, and adding said ID does not work (I wrap the script in a script tag and have added it before and after the anchor).

But, after looking around on Google, I found the following code, which when added makes the Tooltip work as it should.

`$(function () { $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); });`

So, my question is, How the hell do I get it working with the provided Bootstrap code! What am I missing? They really need to work on their instructions. This should not take this long to figure out when it should be simple!

Comment: Why are people down voting this?
If you know how to make it work with the code provided, then provide a solution. There is no reason to down vote it! Especially since it doesn't work as advertised.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate this in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5nrLzfv/). Check the console on your browser if you are getting javascript errors. Looking at the code you have provided though it hits me that you might be mixing two things together. The options need to be defined in your javascript code and not in HTML, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var option = {
    title: "example",
    placement: "bottom"
};
$("#example").tooltip(option);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is about how to read the document of bootstrap.

```
$('#example').tooltip(options)
```

just presents how to use the jquery method, and it is not right for the following html:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!">Hover over me</a>
```

The method must be called in order to active the tooltips plugin. So, in order to make the html working with the plugin, you need to do two steps:

1. add an id into the html, say,

   ```
   <a href="#" id="tips" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!">Hover over me</a>
   ```
2. call the jquery method,

   ```
   $('#tips').tooltip(options)
   ```

Comment: Hey William. Doesn't work for me. The HTML I presented is direct from the Bootstrap instructions, hence part of my confusion. Why reference an ID in the JS but no ID in the HTML code.

I tried your code in replace of mine with the JS above and below, and even changing the jQuery to a hosted version from Google. nothing. But works fine with the other code.

I think perhaps something is conflicting. I'm trying to layout  yoURLs install. Back to the drawing board.